# Remove object from array1 where object.prop is in array2

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

E.g:

```
const array1 = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Bob', age: 29},
  {id: 2, name: 'Anne', age: 18},
  {id: 3, name: 'Dave', age: 29},
  {id: 4, name: 'Barry', age: 50},
  {id: 5, name: 'Jill', age: 35},
];

const array2 = [29, 50];
```

I want to go through `array1` and remove all objects where `object.age` is in `array2`. I have [lodash](https://lodash.com/) at my disposable but their documentation confuses me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [**Array#includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to get the desired result. Filter on the first array and check if the second array contains current item's age and reverse the result.

```js
const array1 = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Bob', age: 29},
  {id: 2, name: 'Anne', age: 18},
  {id: 3, name: 'Dave', age: 29},
  {id: 4, name: 'Barry', age: 50},
  {id: 5, name: 'Jill', age: 35},
];

const array2 = [29, 50];

const mapped = array1.filter(item => !array2.includes(item.age));

console.log(mapped);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with mutating the array (modify in place)

```
_.pullAllBy(array1, [{ age: 29 }, { age: 50 }], 'age');
```

If you want a new array:

```
const newArray = _.differenceBy(array1, [{ age: 29 }, { age: 50 }], 'age');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array.prototype.filter:

```js
var array1 = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Bob', age: 29},
  {id: 2, name: 'Anne', age: 18},
  {id: 3, name: 'Dave', age: 29},
  {id: 4, name: 'Barry', age: 50},
  {id: 5, name: 'Jill', age: 35},
];

var array2 = [29, 50];

var array1 = array1.filter(e => !array2.includes(e.age));

console.log(array1);
```